# Simple addClass on mouseover problem

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm trying to set a class for a li item, with no luck. I have tried many things (to much to post) but I can't figure it out:

```
$("li").live("mouseover",function(){
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

The li item has to change class on mouseover(/hover) and keep that class state even if the mouse hovers *outside* the ul. But (and this is the tricky part) lose the class if another li item is hovered. Which means that the item being hovered gets the ''current'' class.

Hope it makes some sense..This is the fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yomoore/vxJy3/1/)

Comment: I added the code.... it is not too much to post ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the class from all the elements that currently have it before adding it to the new element:

```
$("li").live("mouseover", function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxJy3/2/)

---

For added optimisation (i.e. to save the `$('.current')` selection, which can be expensive in some older browsers), you could check to see if the element hovered already has the class:

```
$("li").live("mouseover", function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('current')) {
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    }
});
```

---

Or, per Felix's excellent idea,

```
var current;
$("li").live("mouseover", function() {
    if (this !== current) {
        $(current).removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        current = this;
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxJy3/2/)

Comment: Thanks:) I wish I was this good, would save me a lot of headache.

Comment: Even better: store a reference to the element that has the `current` class.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the class from its siblings:

```
$("li").live("mouseover",function(){
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("current");
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it for you in the fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxJy3/4/) if you remove the current class from all the li elements and then apply it, you'll have better luck.